# how to edit the data value of the parent component from the child component in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to show or hide the item by clicking the `button` or clicking the item itself, for example:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="show?show = false:show = true">
      {{show?"Hide":"Show"}}
    </button>
    <div @click="show?show = false:show = true" v-if="show">
      Vue Js - click here to Hide
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      show: null,
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

but i want to import the item from another component, so i do this:

**the parent component:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="show?show = false:show = true">
      {{show?"Hide":"Show"}}
    </button>
    <item :show="show" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import item from "item.vue"

export default {
  components: {
    item
  },
  data() {
    return {
      show: null,
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

**the child component:**

```
<template>
  <div @click="show?show = false:show = true" v-if="show">
    Vue Js - click here to Hide
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    show: Boolean,
  }
};
</script>
```

but of course, it doesn't work well.

When i click on the item it disappears but the `show` value in the parent component doesn't change and I get an error saying `Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "show"`.

so how to edit the data value of the parent component from the child component?

(I use Vue 2.6.14)

Comment: I'd suggest using [event emitting](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html?redirect=true) to send updated data up to your parent.

Comment: If **really** needed you can also use Vuex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use [event emitting (Youtube Tutorial)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5pvG6fzkdFM) to send updated data up to the parent component from the child component.
so the code becomes like this:
**the parent component:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="show?show = false:show = true">
      {{show?"Hide":"Show"}}
    </button>
    <item :show="show" @state="update($event)" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import item from "item.vue"

export default {
  components: {
    item
  },
  data() {
    return {
      show: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    update(value) {
      this.show = value;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**the child component:**

```
<template>
  <div @click="action" v-if="show">
    Vue Js - click here to Hide
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    show: Boolean,
  },
  methods: {
    state() {
      if (this.show) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    },
    action() {
      this.$emit("state", this.state())
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Thank you @D.Schaller for helping